# JFlex complaining about caret character

Tags: java, jflex

I'm trying to produce a simple standalone scanner with the use of JFlex. What I want to do now is to simply recognize the beginning of a line with the use of the caret (`^`) symbol.

From the [Semantics section of the user manual](https://jflex.de/manual.html#Semantics):

> In a lexical rule, a regular expression r may be preceded by a ^ (the beginning of line operator).

This is my code right now:

```
// lexer.jflex

%%
%standalone
%class Lexer

beginning = ^

%%

{beginning}     { System.out.println("beginning"); }
.                 { ; }
```

The required behavior is very simple: it should only recognize the beginning of each input line and ignore everything else. However, for some reason, jflex complains about the caret symbol:

```
Error in file "lexer.jflex" (line 5):
Syntax error.
beginning = ^
            ^
```

I also tried with some variations, for example with double quotes around the caret (`"^"`) and escape character before it (`\^`), but obviously this recognizes the caret symbol as a character itself, and not as a regular expression representing the beggining of a line.

EDIT

Problem solved: the caret symbol must not be used in the *options and macros* section but instead in the *actions and rules* section, i.e. the third one. For example, the following code matches the `#` symbol at the beginning of a line:

```
// lexer.jflex

%% 
...
hash = "#"

%%

^{hash} { System.out.println("hash found!"); }
```